# Remove Query Strings from Homepage URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to remove all query strings on the homepage. I tried some methods but they didn't work. I have the following code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ / [QSD,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. Please do mention in your question **from** which URL **to** which URL you want to rewrite OR redirect? That will make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: from www.example.com?231241312anything to www.example.com

Comment: And _what_ have you tried? Please post your implementation so that we can help fix it.